# bind event is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

Whenever I am trying to reload my page this bind event working fine.
But In case of ajax loaded html bind event is not working. How to solve this?

```
$("#customPlayer").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event)
{
 console.log('1');
 var container_width = $('.seek-bar').width();
 $('.play-bar').css({'width':container_width+'px'});
 var current_time = parseFloat(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime);
 if(custom_play_flag)
 {
   if(seek_drag){
     current_time = (duration/container_width) * posX;
     $("#customPlayer").jPlayer("play",current_time);
     seek_drag = false;
   }
 }

 var execute_pecent = (current_time/duration)*container_width;
 $('.progressBar').css({'width':execute_pecent+'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind events on ajax's success handler.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        // DO THE EVENT BINDING HERE..
    }
});
```